# What is "addition unique variance" in structural equation modeling?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I am studying confirmatory factor analysis and playing around with [$\Omega\text{nyx}$](http://onyx.brandmaier.de/). In the user guide, there is the following sentence:

> By default, a double-headed loop is created with each variable, representing addition unique variance of the variable.

**Question 1:** What exactly is this "addition unique variance"?

To put this into context, I have a vanilla factor model where each observable variable $X_j$ is a linear combination of a latent common factor $F_1$ (normalized to have unit variance) with some weight and a latent unique factor / error term $e_j$ with unit weight:
\begin{aligned}
X_1 &= \lambda_1 F_1 + e_1, \\
X_2 &= \lambda_2 F_1 + e_2, \\
X_3 &= \lambda_3 F_1 + e_3. \\
\end{aligned}
$e_j$s are assumed to be uncorrelated. I have tried to implement the model in the graphs below. The left graph contains no "addition unique variances" while the right graph does.

**Question 2:** Which one of them represents my model?

[image]